# Best scroll view in Xcode 5

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios7, interface-builder, scrollview

I'm using a scroll view for half of the screen with the following code which I got from a tutorial:

In .h    `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroller;`

In .m    `@synthesize scroller;` and in viewdidload `[scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1000)];`

I haven't made any other changes. The scroll view works BUT it is very difficult to edit its content in Xcode because I cannot see the full view of the scroll view in storyboard, so how am I supposed to add/edit objects? Or is there a better tutorial out there which I should follow? There was another one which suggested changing the size of the ViewController to Freeform but I couldn't get that one to work.

Thanks

Comment: what you want to do ?

Comment: I need to add multiple labels and buttons in this scrollview. I can do it by readjusting its size on the screen and moving it up/down but I was just wondering if there is an easier way.

Comment: you want to add it runtime or it will be static